# Retrieving ENUMS from a field of a model in LoopBack.io?

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs, loopback4

So given a model in loopback, containing a field (for example) "fruits" with enum value ["apple", "banana", "pear"]. Is there a loopback method I can use to retrieve the enum values of this particular model which I can then later use in let's say a front end application?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using @property({jsonSchema}) to define the enums. If you're using a code generator to generate front-end code based on your app's openapi.json file, the code generator may do this for you. I use @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli and it does. Do you need access to the enums in loopback code?